Redux state not updating during testing after MSW mock request
I'm adding integration tests to key components in my app and I'm having trouble getting things to work as expected between Jest, RTL, Redux (RTK) and MSW. I have set up my environment with the necessary handlers and mock server and components are being rendered with providers using a real instance of the redux store.
I can see the mock request logged but still the UI fails to re-render and/or Redux state is just not updating. Please help!
Test.js
import { screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { renderWithProviders } from '../../utils/test-utils';
import { AdminPage } from './Admin';

describe('<Admin /> initial state', () => {
  const initialState = {
    generatedTOTP: { pin: '' },
  };

  test('Admin page renders with input field and submit button', () => {
    renderWithProviders(<AdminPage />, { preloadedState: initialState });
    const adminPage = screen.getByTestId('admin');
    expect(adminPage).toBeInTheDocument();

    expect(screen.getByTestId('location_id').value).toBe('T');
    expect(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /Submit/i })).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

describe('<Admin /> fetched state', () => {
  const initialState = {
    generatedTOTP: { pin: '' },
  };

  test('Admin page generates new PIN for entered location', async () => {
    renderWithProviders(<AdminPage />, { preloadedState: initialState });

    const inputField = screen.getByPlaceholderText(/Example: T9999/i);
    const submitBtn = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /Submit/i });

    await userEvent.type(inputField, '9999');
    expect(inputField).toHaveValue('T9999');
    await userEvent.click(submitBtn);

    expect(await screen.findByText(/123ABCDE/i)).toBeInTheDocument(); // fails to find this

    // await waitFor(() => {   // alternative method tried
    //   const pinElement = screen.findByText(/123ABCDE/i);
    //   expect(pinElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    // });
  });
});

Page.js
export const AdminPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const accessPin = useSelector((state) => state.generatedTOTP.pin);
  const { loading, error } = useSelector((state) => state.generatedTOTP);

 /* other logic */ 

  return (
    <>
      <Layout.Body data-testid="admin" includeRail>
        <Card>
          <Grid.Container>
            <Grid.Item xs={12} md={12}>
              <Heading size={3}>
                Access PIN Generator
              </Heading>
            </Grid.Item>
            <Grid.Item xs={12} className="hc-pl-md">
              <p>
                Please enter the store ID where the installer is located:
              </p>
            </Grid.Item>
            <Grid.Item xs={12} >
              <Form id="registration_form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <Grid.Container direction="row" align="center">
                  <Grid.Item xs={8} md={4}>
                    <Form.Field
                      id="locationId"
                      data-testid="location_id"
                      label="Location ID"
                      placeholder="Example: T9999"
                      type="text"
                      required={true}
                      error={errors.locationId}
                      errorText={errors.locationId && errors.locationId.message}
                      {...register('locationId', {
                        required: true,
                        pattern: {
                          value: /T[0-9]{4}/,
                          message:
                            'Invalid location ID! Please follow this format: T1234',
                        },
                        maxLength: {
                          value: 5,
                          message:
                            'Error! Location ID needs to be 5 characters long',
                        },
                        minlength: {
                          value: 5,
                          message:
                            'Error! Location ID needs to be 5 characters long',
                        },
                      })}
                    />
                  </Grid.Item>
                  <Grid.Item xs={4}>
                    <Button label="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" />
                  </Grid.Item>
                </Grid.Container>
              </Form>
            </Grid.Item>

            <Grid.Item xs={12}>
              {loading && <Spinner className="center" />}
              {error && (
                <Message type="error">
                  <p>There was a problem generating a PIN. Please try again.</p>
                </Message>
              )}
              {accessPin && (
                <div>
                  <p>Temporary access PIN</p>
                  <Chip clickable={true}>
                    {accessPin}
                  </Chip>
                </div>
              )}
            </Grid.Item>
          </Grid.Container>
        </Card>
      </Layout.Body>
    </>
  );
};

handlers and providers
import { http, HttpResponse } from 'msw';

export const handlers = [
  // Intercept "GET generate/totp" requests...
  http.get(
    '/generate/totp',
    () => {
      console.log('Captured a "GET /generate/totp" request');
      // ...and respond using this JSON response:
      return HttpResponse.json({
        data: '123ABCDE',
      });
    },
  ),
];

import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { InstallerAuthContextProvider } from '../context/InstallerAuthContext';

import setupStore from '../app/store';

export function renderWithProviders(ui, extendedRenderOptions = {}) {
  const {
    preloadedState = {},
    store = setupStore(preloadedState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = extendedRenderOptions;

  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <InstallerAuthContextProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>{children}</BrowserRouter>
      </InstallerAuthContextProvider>
    </Provider>
  );

  return {
    store,
    ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }),
  };
}

